# QImage from unsigned char buffer (jpg format)

Tags: c++, image, qt, jpeg

I have buffer of type `unsigned char*` which I fill with JPG image.  I want to use this buffer to draw the image to my application screen in a QLabel.

I've done this, but the image is incorrect.

Can anyone tell me what the best way to do this is?

```
QPixmap pix = QPixmap::fromImage(
     QImage(buff, 460, 345, QImage::Format_RGB888)); //Not sure what format to use for a jpg image?

one_img->setPixmap(pix);  //one_img is of type QLabel.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QImage::load` or the `QImage` constructor expect the image buffer to be in an uncompressed format.

If you don't intend to modify the image, use `QPixmap` and its `loadFromData()` function:

```
QPixmap pix;
pix.loadFromData(buff, sizeOfBuff, "JPG");
```

You can also load a Jpeg buffer with `QImage::fromData` / `QImage::loadFromData`, or `QImageReader` + `QBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this has to do with the image format. It depends on the way you load the image into the buffer. `QImage` expects to find an image stored line by line in the provided buffer.

Try the `Format_Indexed8` or `Format_RGB32` image formats. If it still does not work let us know how you have loaded the `jpeg` image into the buffer.

Notice that `QImage` provides a [constructor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html#QImage-9) with the image filename as argument.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is not to interpret the jpg data as RGB format, and use appropriate class, like for example [QImageReader](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qimagereader.html), or event use [the constructor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qimage.html#QImage-9) to load the image directly.

Answer (score 0):

you said that you fill the buffer with an jpg, so it seem that you have an image already saved.
if so the best way is to use:

`QPixmap ( const QString & fileName, const char * format = 0, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor )`

where :

```
filename is the path to the image 
format is in your case "JPG" or JPEG 
flags  is to specify if the image is black white or color (see the documentation for details)
```